# Binding error in MSSQL Views 'DWView.dbo.whatever'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was given a database by a client.  I can't access any of the data in the Views in this database because I get this error:

Invalid object name 'DWView.dbo.Person_C'.

I have no user/role/anything called DWView.  The view exists, but nothing can access it.  This happens in all of the views.

One thing I'm not clear on -- what is DWView.dbo?  I know dbo is the schema/owner, but what about the DWView part?  I've never encountered this in 15+ years of working with MSSQL databases.

Any attempt to access the views fails with that error, including sp_refreshview.

Is there anything I can do to remove this DWView thing?  Thanks.

Comment: you are using three part name to access your view it should be `[database].[schema].[objectname]` in your select query I would assume  `DWView` is your database name.

Answer (score 1):

The error means the object doesn't exist.  Like you mentioned, the schema comes before the view in syntax; so when you ask ...

> One thing I'm not clear on -- what is DWView.dbo

... it means `database.schema`.  So your query is looking for the database `DWView`, the schema `dbo`, and the object name `Person_C`.

As a note, if you're already on the database (`USE Database GO`), you don't have to use the database in your query; you can simply use `SchemaName.ObjectName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing this ..

```
USE Your_Database_Name
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Person_C
GO
```

It should be `[database].[schema].[objectname]`.

Comment: The db used to be called school_linkage.  So I renamed it to DWView just to see what would happen.  Now if I try to "Edit 200 Rows" in Mgt Studio, it says, "view or function DWView.dbo.Person_C contains a self-reference."  If I try select * from [DWView].[dbo].[Person_C] I get "invalid object name."  If I leave off DWView, same result.